# Is it possible to create a video with rolling credit effect using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Suppose I have a text file and background image.

I am wondering if ffmpeg can create a video like this:

[image]

Comment: FFmpeg can simulate the effect but not neatly format the text. Best to generate a single image with all credits and then do a roving crop.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks. Do you know how to simulate the effect? Any format is fine.

Comment: Once you have an image, ingest it with `-loop 1` and then apply a crop `-vf crop=iw:720:0:28*n` This will create an output 720 px tall. And pan down the image 28 pixels per frame.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks a lot!!